# Putting quotes from the Talmud/Torah on the wall

Tags: halacha

What are the halachic issues which might come up in printing verses of the Talmud and Torah and sticky-taping them on a wall? One example would be **[Taanit 20a:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.20a.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - 20b:3.**

Comment: Many people have eishes chayil hanging in their living room. What would be the problem that your thinking of? Many Shul’s have signs hanging with a quote of the Gemara about the importance of yeheh shmei raba etc. succah decorations have many pesukim and quotes on them and the only issue I’ve ever heard is what to do with them after use. Please elaborate what issue you could possibly have

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Uriel and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!